# TSQL Not equal operator with respect to dates

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

```
SELECT * FROM TABLE_NAME
WHERE 
([DateOfLastTransaction] <> @p29) 
OR ([DateOfLastTransaction] <> @p30)

@p29='2012-11-30 00:00:00.000',  3 records
@p30='2012-04-17 00:00:00.000'  1 record
```

I got the query from SQL profiler and have removed unnecessary bits.Removing the OR and the @p30 parameter returns 3 records. Is it the "OR" impacting it?

I have 4 records (which need excluding) with the 2 dates and my query doesn't work. Why is that? Am I doing something very stupid?

Comment: Did you mean, `AND`?  Are you wanting to return all dates that are not equal to @p29 AND are not equal to @p30?

Comment: You are using logical OR (c# ||) in your Linq query.You need to use logical AND (c# &&).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider this statement

```
SELECT * FROM TABLE_NAME
WHERE 
   [DateOfLastTransaction] <> @p29 
OR [DateOfLastTransaction] <> @p30
```

Unless [DateOfLastTransaction] is null
Or @p29 = @p29 = [DateOfLastTransaction]
It will always return true

If the date matches neither
true or true evaluates to true

If the date matches @p29
false or true evaluates to true

If the date matches @p30
true or false evaluates to true

Answer (score 3):

I believe you meant to use the `AND` logical operator.  e.g.

```
SELECT *
FROM Table_Name
WHERE 
     [DateOfLastTransaction] != @p29
     AND [DateOfLastTransaction] != @p30
```

Everything will return with the `OR` operator, as `[DateOfLastTransaction]` may qualify on the first logical comparison but be invalidated on the second.